# Receiving response as JSON in ajax call in jsp

Tags: ajax, spring

I have a jsp page that sends response as a json. The page is requested through AJAX call. But the response went into Ajax error part instead of success part.

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

The following is my jsp page Script:

```
$("#Student").delegate("select[id='year.id']", "change", function () {
         //alert("hi");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value=$("select[id='year.id']").val();
        //alert(id);
        //alert(value);
       //console.log($(id).val());
        $("select[id='classs.id']").empty();
        $("select[id='classs.id']").append('<option value="">Select Class</option>');
        $("select[id='section.id']").empty();
        $("select[id='section.id']").append('<option value="">Select Section</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getStandard',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { Year: value },
            success : function(datas) {     
                $.each(datas, function (i, data) {
                    $("select[id='classs.id']").append('<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This Is my server side code where I am getting the response as Student object :

Controller :

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/getStudentName", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getStudentName(@RequestParam("Year") String idYear, @RequestParam("Classs") String idClass, @RequestParam("Section") String idSection) throws JsonProcessingException 
{       
    List<Student> student = userService.getStudentName(idYear,idClass,idSection);       

     return student ;
}
```

I am new to ajax using via Spring

Comment: can anyone tell where i am doing the Mistake ?

Comment: my success function is giving the error (The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers)

Comment: After lots of research i found a way to get this solved, I converted the model object to Json string in the controller side using  ObjectMapper, Then in my ajax function i have used $.parseJSON(datas) to omit the null values . I have updated the code, Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam is a parameter in the uri (http://uri?year=2018). If what you want is JSON then you should use @RequestBody instead

Comment: Moreover you can't use @RequestBody on a GET method

Comment: Yes that is true, I didn't check the method.

Comment: wethere i have to add any dependencies for Json in maven ??

Comment: I don't see why you need another dependency.

Comment: Request is hitting the controller and i am able to process the data from the database as student object, But the In success function the student object is not getting any values insead it goes to error function

Comment: this is the error Im getting :   The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Comment: What did you change ?  (As Angelo said if you change to @RequestBody you need to use POST method instead of GET.)Maybe edit your question to allow everybody to answer your question.

Comment: I didnt changed to @RequestBody im still using RequestParam

Comment: Yes it seems more logical to use @RequestParam. And so you change your client

Comment: can anyone tell where im doing the mistake ?